# Wait for 1 second before starting code again - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, wait

I desperately need help with a game I am making. For a bit of context, i am making a memory game and i have the following piece of code that is being troublesome. I have a bunch of labels on the form, 16 to be exact, with 1 randomly generated symbol placed in each. Each symbol appears in the labels twice.

```
      ------------------------------Continued----------------------------------------
                'MsgBox("hello") 'used to check if the second inccorect press shows up - it does show but instantly changes colour
                '''''''''''''''''NEED SOME CODE THAT PAUSES IT HERE'''''''''''''''
                labels(0).ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
                sender.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed
            End If
            flips = 1
        End If
    End If
    tmrmemory.Enabled = True ' starts the timer after the user clicks the first label
End Sub
```

What's supposed to happen is that when the labels clicked don't match, it should show both the clicked labels for a short period before changing them both back to "DarkRed" which is the colour of the form's background.

I have tried using a timer but then i can't use `sender.forecolor=color.darkred` because it is not declared globally.

I have also tried using the command `Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)` but it still doesn't show the second incorrect click. I know that the code i have used works because when i use the message box, i can see both symbols and when the two clicks are correct, it stays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)` will actually pause your code for half a second. However during this time it won't do anything, not even refresh your controls. To get the effect you want, you need to call the `YourControl.Refresh` method before calling `Threading.Thread.Sleep` to force the control to redraw immediately.

On a side note, I would advise you not to call `Threading.Thread.Sleep` on UI thread. It will give a feeling of program hang. Instead do your work on a separate thread. You can either do all the work yourself right from creating a separate thread to destroying it, or use the `BackgroundWorker` control which has all the functionality built in.

Here is the link to an article I wrote a long time ago regarding BackgroundWorker that might be useful for you:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?680130-Correct-way-to-use-the-BackgroundWorker

Comment: Thank you very much, i ended up using `Me.Refresh` before using `Threading.Thread.Sleep` and this fixed up my issue. But yes, i did notice that the form hangs during this period rendering it unresponsive. I read through your article but can't seem to get my head around it, I'm still quite new to VB and coding for that matter. I'll probably just stick with the Threading function for now, unless i figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Was there an alternative to the `me.refresh` command that does not make the form look as if it is flickering or in better words "refreshing?" It's just an aesthetic thing

Comment: Set the form's `DoubleBuffered` property to True. That should take care of the flickering issue. Also if the number of controls to be refreshed is not large then call each control's Refresh method instead of refreshing the whole form.

Comment: Doesn't seem as if the `DoubleBuffered`property was causing it, it was definitely the `Me.Refresh` command refreshing the whole form. Changed it to just the control. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable outside the sub that stores what label should be flipped when the timer ends.

Label click sets 
`storedLabel = sender` 
Timer tick sets  `storedLabel.ForeColor = Color.DarkRed`